# UI Elements jump way off the current view controller after adding to stack view (iOS)

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uistackview, xcode9.2

What I want to discuss here is the issues that I have encountered using stack views.

Problem:

Have:

Image lets say 200 x 300
UILabel - as a header
UILabel - as a body text
UIButton - background image 150 x 50

the UILabel labels jump way off the current view controller and have a size of 9,000 + width and height something strange as well.

Problem in detail:

[image]

Why does this happen? How to prevent this and how to fix this?

Solution?

Note: I welcome everybody’s feed back with this one. It has not happened just once but many many times to me.

Comment: Just make sure you set the proper constraints for the `stackView` itself (it has to have position and size setup properly), and that you set correct distribution, axis, and alignment on it

Comment: Hi Milan, thank for that. I thought that the stack view autosizes to the largest element in the stack? How to size the stack so that the longest text field is shown?

Comment: can you share your storyboard file?